# How to run .profile from .bashrc file?

Tags: prompt, .profile

I have a file name .test with a echo statement. Now I want to run this file from .bashrc file. What I have done so far is:

My .test file contains:

```
echo "hello everyone"
```

My .bashrc file contains:

```
echo "hello world"
```

Now what I want is to run .test file from .bashrc file and here is what I did

In .bashrc file

```
echo "hello world"
ENV=$(/home/narwen/.test)
echo $ENV
```

Now when I try to run the .bashrc file from prompt like this

```
. .bashrc
```

I get

hello world

and errors like this

```
XAUTHORITY=/home/niraj/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/env
=
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Again, you are using SPACES in the variable, just don't use trailing spaces! It should be `ENV=VAR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
. /path/to/.test
```

or:

```
source /path/to/.test
```

Or, if you want to keep the output of `. /path/to/.test` in a variable `ENV`, then use:

```
ENV=$(. /path/to/.test)
```

So, please don't use spaces around the `=` in assignments.

And later, you can use `$ENV` variable something  like:

```
echo $ENV
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you are not getting my point. I have placed one echo statement in .bashrc file and one echo statement in .test file. Now I want to display the echo statement of .test file from .bashrc file.So how can I do it?

Comment: Exactly how I said.

Comment: what do you mean by that? I think you are not getting me or i am unable to explain it to you.

Comment: @Narwen See my new edits.

Comment: Can you please revisit the question? I have just edited it.

Comment: @Narwen I told you from the first time, **please don't use spaces around the `=` in assignments.** This will give you error: `ENV =$(.test)`. Correct is `ENV=$(.test)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `.test` file is being executed as a script. Instead, you may need to fork a shell to apply the ENV variable to the shell:

```
$ . .bash
$ echo $ENV
something
$
```

My `.test` file has `echo "something"` as content and `.bash` has `ENV=$(. /home/braiam/.test)`:

```
$ cat .bash
ENV=$(. /home/braiam/.test)
$ cat .test
echo "something"
```

Comment: No dice. When you source a file, that file doesn't need to be executable.

Comment: I have tried that providing executable permission but still i am getting the same result.

Comment: @Narwen use the later part of Radu's answer, you need to fork a shell before you can source it. As you are doing it is just executing the `.` and `.test`.